# Why is frequency spectrum centred at 1 kHz?

Tags: simulation, frequency, matlab, frequency-modulation

This is the circuit that I have built

[image]

I set the Continuous-Time VCO to a frequency of 1 kHz. Since there is no message signal the modulation index is =0 meaning I would expect one peak and I would expect that one peak to centred around fc which is 1 kHz.  However, when I run it I'm getting it centred around 1.1 kHz as shown below:

[image]

Comment: The message signal is 1, not 0, in your block diagram screenshot. What is the VCO's gain (in hertz per volt)?

Comment: @nanofarad the gain is 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message signal is 1, and the VCO's gain is 100 Hz/V. Hence, the deviation is 100 Hz, and your 1.1 kHz (= 1 kHz center frequency + 100 Hz offset) peak is as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @Lilyg8614 If this answer answers your question, please mark it as accepted using the checkmark to the left (or mark another answer if a better one comes in). Otherwise, let me know if there's any info to be added.